# Get last UserID from SqlServer to textbox control

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table `customers` where each cust has `UserID` as **"A000"** now I need to get the **last** entered **`ID`** from the database and display it in my textbox.

Can anyone suggest me how do I do this?

As I have seen many articles describing about

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')
```

but unable to know where to use it correctly.

And here is how I'm doing it :

```
 Dim strConnection As String = "Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=Subscription;Integrated Security=True"
 'Establish SQL Connection
 Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
 'Open database connection to connect to SQL Server
 con.Open()
 'Data table is used to bind the resultant data
 Dim dtusers As New DataTable()
 'Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT MAX(UserID) FROM Customers", con)
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
 da.Fill(dtusers)
 con.Close()
```

Comment: Is the ID separate to the UserID in your table schema? If so you can use SELECT MAX (like you already did). If you actually want to pass the value back from a stored procedure as soon as it is created you will need to create an OUT parameter and link it to the SQLCommand.

Comment: No, the ID is different from UserID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) :

```
Dim comm as new SqlCommand
comm.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(UserID) FROM Customers"
comm.Connection = con

Dim MaxUserID as object = comm.ExecuteScalar()
```

> Use the ExecuteScalar method to retrieve a single value (for example,
>   an aggregate value) from a database

Side Note : `ExecuteScalar()` may return a null reference (Nothing in VB.NET) if the result of the command is empty like when there are no records in the table or there is condition that doesn't produce any records. Make sure you check that before assigning the value to your TextBox.

Comment: @coder why not? do you get an error? make sure you set the `comm.Connection` to your `SqlConnection`

Comment: It is not throwing me any error but not getting into debugging mode.

Comment: @AbZy, there is a big difference between DBNull and null, ExecuteScalar returns null (Nothing in VB.NET) when there is no result for the command executed (e.g. no rows in the Customers table)